# Does spring-context support JSR-330 Qualifier on bean instances?

Tags: java, spring, qualifiers, jsr330

Spring has its own `Qualifier` annotation, I think it's equivalent to the `javax.inject.Named` annotation, which in turn is a concrete qualifier in JSR-330.

So, I'm wondering which version of Spring, if any, supports Qualifier?

Here is my example usage, unfortunately it doesn't work with spring-context 3.0.5:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@javax.inject.Qualifier
public @interface Version {

    String value();

}

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean("book-12") @Version("a") Book book12a() { ... }

    @Bean("book-12") @Version("b") Book book12b() { ... }

}

@Component
public class UserClass {

    @Inject @Named("book-12") Book anybook12;

    @Inject @Named("book-12") @Version("b") Book book12_b;

}
```

Comment: It will work for spring. Look for my post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446870/jsr-330-qualifier-not-working-with-java-based-spring-configuration

Comment: @sharath the link is dead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it supports all `javax.inject.*` annotations. I myself have used the `javax.inject.Qualifier`

Btw, I assume you want `@Service` or `@Component` instead of `@Bean`, and you need your `Book` class to be made spring-managed.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik use `@Service` rather than `@Bean`

Comment: @Bozho: `@Service` and `@Component` are `ElementType.TYPE` targeted, but I don't want to create extra types. So, I guess `@Bean` won't work, right?

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik no. you must have a `Book` class that is annotated and made spring-managed.

Comment: I have used @Bean for @Configuration definition and it works fine, albeit haven't used it with qualifiers.

Comment: @CarlosZ @谢继雷'Lenik well, using java-config (`@Configuration`) perhaps doesn't work with qualifiers.